# \bold in math environment

Tags: fonts, macros, bold

Having forgotten the command to make text bold in math mode I naively tried

```
$\bold{bold var goes here} these maths symbols are not bold$
```

and it worked! I became immediately suspicious as I know LaTeX font commands are never that `nice'. I haven't been able to find anything about this command online. By experimentation I found that amsfonts or amssymb are responsible.

My main question is to please explain where this command came from: where in which package.
The additional question is how can one find out where any given command comes from using just his computer (if not possible, then the easiest way with the internet)?

Comment: `\boldmath` for steady bold font and `\bm` for local changes (or `\mathbf{}`). There's an outdated command also, but I can't never remember which one it is.

Comment: The syntax `\bold{...}` works with AMS-TeX, not with LaTeX.

Comment: `\boldmath` must be stipulated *outside* of math mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before answering your main question, I’ll deal with the additional one: at least in TeX Live, there is a command-line utility program called `texdef` by means of which you can easily see how, and sometimes where, a command is defined, or, more generally, what is its meaning.

The basic syntax is

```
texdef -t <format> <cs>
```

where `<format>` is the name of a TeX format, *e.g.*, `latex`, and `<cs>` is any control sequence (not necessarily a command or a macro name).  There are also a full bunch of command-line options, among which I’d recall:

- `-c <class>`, for specifying a `<class>` different from the default
  `article` class;
- `-p <package>`, or more generally `-p [<options>]{<package>}`,
  to load a certain `<package>`, possibly with `<options>`;
- `-s`, to (try to) show an extract of the source file where a certain
  command is defined;
- `-h` (help) is very useful too, of course!

For example—and I am coming, now, to your main question—if you try

```
texdef -t latex -p amssymb -s \bold
```

the answer you get, namely

```
% amsfonts.sty, line 115:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bold}[1]{%
  {\@subst@obsolete{amsfonts}\bold\mathbf{#1}}}
```

tells you that `\bold` is defined on line 115 of the file `amsfonts.sty`, as syntactic sugar to support an old, and now deprecated, command, effectively converting it into `\mathbf`.

Answer (score 6):

Some options, but not all, I think, to use bold math in LaTeX:

`\boldmath` is your friend if there's a longer portion of bold math fonts needed, not just a few symbols. Don't forget to use `\unboldmath` later on.

`\mathbf{...}` is the math bold version of `\textbf`, i.e. the font is `roman` and upright letters usually.

The package `bm` provides the `\bm` command, amongst other features.

The `\boldsymbol` command keeps the usual italic shaped letters of the math environments.

The `\bold` command is from `AMS-TeX` and works if the package `amsfonts` or `amssymb` is loaded, but there's a warning that `\bold` is deprecated:

```
Package amsfonts Warning: Obsolete command \bold; \mathbf should be used instea
d on input line 24


\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\foo}{E=mc^{2}}


\begin{document}
Not bold: $\foo$

From now on all bold with \verb!\boldmath!: \boldmath $\foo$ 

or $E^{2} = p^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4}$\unboldmath 

-- from here the enduring effect of \verb!\boldmath! has been removed with \verb!\unboldmath!

Local bold math with font change by \verb!\mathbf!: $\mathbf{\foo}$

Local bold math with \verb!\bm! from package \texttt{bm}: $\bm{\foo}$


With \verb!\bold! command:  $\bold{\foo}$ 

\end{document}
```

There's also `\boldsymbol` from `amsmath` and `\pmb`("poor man's bold"), the latter being a last resort method for symbols which have no true bold version in the font.

Comment: +1. You may want to state more explicitly that (a) `\mathbf` generates **bold-upright** letters whereas `\bm` and `\boldsymbol` generate ***bold-italic*** letters, and also (b) `\mathbf` has no effect on math symbols (e.g, `\sigma` and `\sum`) whereas `\bm` and `\boldsymbol` do have an effect. Finally, it may be worth noting that this is specific to "TeX math mode". With other systems, such as French math mode and ISO math mode, different conventions may apply

Comment: @campa: Actually, I missed the `bold` somehow. I will add

Answer (score 0):

The `unicode-math` package is partly backward-compatible, but the rules are slightly different.

The `\mathbf` command still works, but is meant for words in math mode.  The recommended way to get individual math symbols is `\symbfup` or `\symbfit`.  The `amsmath` command `\bold` will therefore still work.

IF you load an OpenType math font that has a bold version (as of 2019, XITS, Libertinus or Minion), `unicode-math` will switch to it when you select `\boldmath` or `\mathversion{bold}`.  You can also do something like `\setmathfont[version=bold]{MinionMath-Semibold.otf}`.  The `\boldsymbol` command from `amsmath` still works and is a very convenient way to switch to the bold math version.